# How to save the preview render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I accidentally set the preview sample rate to 3329 samples. I left blender to go eat food, and when I came back, the render was surprisingly good.

I don't want to render for another 4 hours, is there a way to save the preview render?

(besides taking a screenshot, I have that already.)[image]

Comment: The answer is no =)

Comment: awwwwwwwwwwwwwww... It's too late anyway because I already re-rendered it, but if the answer exists, it would still be useful for future knowledge

Comment: In fact the image must be présent in a buffer somewhere on the hard drive but if you ever managed to retrieve it, the resolution wouldn't be higher than the preview window's size.

Comment: I know that the resolution wouldn't be higher than the preview windows size, but the image would also keep the things off to the side of the preview window

Comment: AFAIK, the viewport buffer is not ever saved to the hard drive. It only exists in the blender process' RAM space.